# Does the vue.js component require a name option?

Tags: vue.js

If I don't set the name in the component, can it cause any problems?
Even if I don't set it, I can use it.

```js
    <template>
      <div> some component</div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
        name: "SomeComponent" // is this essential?
    };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When registering a component, its **ID** is required, but **Name** is not.

As [Vue's Component Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-component) says:

> Registration also automatically sets the component’s `name` with the given `id`.

So it would be fine to leave `component.name` blank when declaring only one component. But, it is always better practice to give names to your components, especially in a large application. **[Vue's Component Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#name)** explains this at a greater length:

> Allow the component to recursively invoke itself in its template. Note that when a component is registered globally with `Vue.component()`, the global ID is automatically set as its name.
>
> Another benefit of specifying a `name` option is debugging. Named components result in more helpful warning messages. Also, when inspecting an app in the [vue-devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/devtools), unnamed components will show up as `<AnonymousComponent>`, which isn’t very informative. By providing
> the `name` option, you will get a much more informative component tree.

Comment: I haven't seen `<AnonymousComponent>` show up as described above. If I don't specify a name of a component, the devtools will use the name under which it was registered in its parent component.

Comment: Hm, so if element is not recursive I guess there is no reason to specify a name.